# Jmeter: Could anyone explain me detailed explanation of the following terms in Graph Results?

Tags: performance, jmeter

Jmeter: Could anyone explain me detailed explanation of the following terms in Graph Results?
I have looped single user request for 100 time (i.e no of samples :100) for www.google.com and then i got following result in graph results:

```
    No of samples: 100
    Deviation: 86
    Latest Sample: 90 
    Throughput: 504.202/minute 
    Average: 117 (average of what) 
    Median: 89 (median of what)
```

and also which parameters are most important to observe to get its performance?

Comment: please check :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448516/apache-jmeter-listener-results-interpretation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all check [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for definition of basic load testing terms

In regards to median and average, as per [The Load Reports guide](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports)

> **#Samples** is the number of samples with the same label.
>
> **Average** is the average time of a set of results.
>
> **Median** is a number which divides the samples into two equal halves. Half of the samples are smaller than the median, and half are larger. [Some samples may equal the median.] This is a standard statistical measure. The Median is the same as the 50th Percentile.
>
> **90% Line** (90th Percentile) meaning 90% of the samples took no more than this time.
>
> **Min** is the shortest time for the samples with the same label
>
> **Max** is the longest time for the samples with the same label
>
> **Error %** is the percent of requests with errors
>
> **Throughput** is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.
>
> **Kb/sec** - throughput measured in Kilobytes per second. Time is in milliseconds.

So it is time in milliseconds for [Arithmetic Mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) and [Median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) for all the requests correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T for this kind information. It really did helped me..